# missing java source files after brew cask install adoptopenjdk11

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, adoptopenjdk

having installed java via `brew cask install adoptopenjdk11`

using it in e.g. vscode works fine.

But I want to "go to definition" of jdk classes and investigate the source `.java` code of jdk classes.

Is there a way to "add" jdk sources which vscode "recognizes" with F-12 "Go to Definition" ?

Comment: hmmm, just realizing that code completion does not work also on brew installed java and vscode ... $JAVA_HOME is set correctly:  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling the jdk solved the problem